# After concat text i get NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, varchar

I try concat 2 string and reverse it but in result I get NULL not a text
for ex. first string "a1" second string "b2" result "21ba"

```
CREATE function addToString(@val1 varchar(100),@val2 varchar(100))
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
    declare @i as int
    declare @output as varchar(200)
    if len(@val1)!=len(@val2)
        set @output='length error: '+cast(len(@val1) as varchar(10))+
        '<>'+cast(len(@val2) as varchar(10)) 
    else
        select @i=len(@val1)-1
        while @i>=0
            begin
                set @output= concat(@output,substring(@val2,@i,1))
                set @output= concat(@output,substring(@val1,@i,1))  
                set @i=@i-1
            end
    return @output
end
go
select dbo.[addToString]('a1','b2') as txt
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server.  You should also explain what the code is supposed to do and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `NULL` values.  Possibly the simplest way is to just replace it with an empty string at the top of the stored procedure:

```
select @val2 = coalesce(@val2, '');
```

Or, declare the parameters to be `NOT NULL` so `NULL` values are not passed in.

Comment: @OVDC . . . Or drop the procedure first.  Either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong and you don't initialize @output:

```
CREATE function addToString(@val1 varchar(100),@val2 varchar(100))
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
    declare @i as int

 -- declare @output as varchar(200) -- initialized to NULL
    declare @output as varchar(200) = ''

    if len(@val1)!=len(@val2)
        set @output='length error: '+cast(len(@val1) as varchar(10))+
        '<>'+cast(len(@val2) as varchar(10)) 
    else
     -- select @i=len(@val1)-1 -- strips the last char
        select @i=len(@val1)

     -- while @i>=0
        while @i>0

            begin
                set @output= concat(@output,substring(@val2,@i,1))
                set @output= concat(@output,substring(@val1,@i,1))  
                set @i=@i-1
            end
    return @output
end
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -1 from the len function

```
  CREATE function addToString(@val1 varchar(100),@val2 varchar(100))
    returns varchar(200)
    as
    begin
        declare @i as int
        declare @output as varchar(200)
        if len(@val1)!=len(@val2)
            set @output='length error: '+cast(len(@val1) as varchar(10))+
            '<>'+cast(len(@val2) as varchar(10)) 
        else
            select @i=len(@val1)
            while @i>=0
                begin
                    set @output= concat(@output,substring(@val2,@i,1))
                    set @output= concat(@output,substring(@val1,@i,1))  
                    set @i=@i-1
                end
        return @output
    end
    go
    select dbo.[addToString]('a1','b2') as txt
```